# Replace the "et" to "and" with Hermes document class

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I use the hermes document styles for Latex,
I think this style is for french, so for example i have the citation (oard et dikelma, 1998), i want to replace it by (oard and dikelma, 1998)

```
\documentclass{article-hermes}  
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\addto\captionsenglish{\def\tablename{Table}}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

....

\bibliography{hemres}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! It seems you have to declare the document class with option `[english]`.

Comment: According to http://eric.univ-lyon2.fr/~jds03/Consignes/doc-article-hermes-ori.pdf this document class uses BibTeX and not `biblatex`, so I have re-tagged your question to reflect that.

Comment: Which conjunctions -- `et` or `and` -- are in the citation call-outs and in the bib entries depends on the bibliography style file. Which bibliography style do you use?

Answer (score 3):

i find the soluion very simple, but very difficult to find

you must add the option[english]

```
\documentclass[english]{article-hermes}
```